# How can I edit the environment Path string in a proper editor (in Win7)?

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

Is there a file somewhere with environment Path, that I can edit with a plain editor and use to update the system variable? Kind of like the old config.sys.

Using the System page just shows a tiny bit of the string at a time, and has a primitive editor. 
I want to see it all at once, so I can see if there are duplicates, or if I should sort the entries.

This is for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try googling for "Path Editor" and you may just find a custom-built free utility to do this.